# How to use the volumes package?

Tags: document-configuration

I need to split a book in two volumes, the problem is that I need the table of contents and the index of the whole book in each volume. I already tried to use the package `volumes` but I can't make it work.

```
\usepackage{volumes}
\onlyvolume
```

And according to the documentation I should put `\volumeone` and `\volumetwo` but after installig the package these commands are not recognized.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You tagged your question with `biblatex`, `bibtex` and `bibliographies`, but I cannot recognize how those tags relate to your question. Therefore please elaborate your question a bit more to account for this topic or remove the tags as they would lead to a mis-categorization.

Comment: The `\volumeone`, `\volumetwo`, …, `\volumeten` macros are only defined if the package is called with the `manual` option; however they shouldn't be necessary, unless there are problem with other packages trying to redefine `\include`, according to the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you publish in print, the solution is easy:

1. Keep the whole opus in one main file (maybe using \include etc.)
2. Compile the file with TOC
3. Save your TOC as a extra PDF (e.g. by sending only the TOC pages to a PDF printer and the like)
4. Now split your main file in two and set the first pagenumber of the second part to the pagenumber it had before.
5. Before this first page include the TOC-PDF, using the pdfpages package.

You know how to switch between roman pagenumbers for the frontmatter and arabic pagenumbers of the mainmatter? But this depends on the documentclass.

So you need to find out how to deal with pagenumbering. We can help you, as soon as you tell us more about the documentclass and maybe give us an MWE. Minimal working examples for large documents are easy with the blindtext package and the command `\blinddocument`.

If you publish a PDF, things are more complicated, because you'll probably wish to have hyperlinks from the TOC to the chapters and sections.